# Importing planet OSM using osm2pgsql Issues

Tags: openstreetmap

I used osm2pgsql to import the entire planet-osm into my PostGIS data.  It took a whole week and finally finished during the week-end when I was not at work.  Also, some how the server restarted during the week-end so did not know whether the import was successful.  From my previous experience with osm2pgsql, it would rollback if it encountered errors during import.  It did not rollback this time and I assumed the import was successful. However when I inspected the indexes of the planet_osm_line, planet_osm_roads, and planet_osm_polygon, I only saw one index created instead of two.  The planet_osm_*_index was missing.  Not sure what happened.  I am greatly appreciated if someone tell me what is going on and whether there is anyway to fix the problem.  Note: The reason I know the index was missing because I was successfully imported a small region of OSM data before and saw two indexes, the "*_index" and "*_pkey".  The command I used for import was:

osm2pgsql -s -m -d planet-osm -E 3857 -S default.style planet-osm-*.bz2

Many thanks in advance.

Regards,
Tam

Comment: I suggest to ask this question at help.openstreetmap.org where you will reach a much larger OSM community.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but if you as operator can't provide us details, how can we help? So I suggest to restart the procedure with a small dump so you test if your procedure works in general